# APA7 references with classic thesis style by André Miede

Tags: biblatex, biber, classicthesis, apa7

I'm struggling to have APA7 references using the classic thesis style by André Miede (see [here](https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/classic-thesis-style-v4-dot-2-by-andre-miede/dwgtvykzvdtk) for the template I'm using).

The initial biblatex options are as follows:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{%
    backend = bibtex8, bibencoding = ascii,%
    language = auto,%
    style = numeric-comp,%
    sorting = nyt, % name, year, title
    maxbibnames = 10, % default: 3, et al.
    natbib = true % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still work)
}{biblatex}
    \usepackage{biblatex}
```

I modified them to have APA7 formatting:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{%
    % backend=biber, %instead of bibtex
    backend = bibtex8, bibencoding = ascii,%
    language = auto,%
    style = apa,
    natbib = true % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still work)
}{biblatex}
    \usepackage{biblatex}
```

This is working, but I have this mistake:

```
Package biblatex Error: Biber backend is required by style.

l.16 \RequireBiber[3]
                     
The selected style or one of the .bib files requires Biber.
It will not work at all with BibTeX..
```

If I'm using biber instead of bibtex8, the citations are not printed:

[image]

I would really appreciate some help here... Thanks a lot.

Comment: `biber` is strictly required. You can simply remove `backend = bibtex8` or explicitly declare `backend=biber`

Comment: As Ivan says, you **must** use Biber with `biblatex-apa`. `biblatex-apa` simply does not work with BibTeX or BibTeX8. So you should replace `backend=bibtex8,` with `backend=biber,`. Usually that is not enough. You also need to make sure to call Biber instead of BibTeX/BibTeX8 when you compile your document. If you run compilation from the command line that is as easy as saying `biber file` instead of `bibtex file`. But if you are using an editor to run the compilation steps for you, you may have to reconfigure it as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: @Ivan Do you want to type up a quick answer here, so the question can be marked as answered?